# Find frequency of an element in sorted array in logn

Tags: c++, complexity-theory

Is this possible?
I came up with this:

```
void binary_search(int list[], int lo, int hi, int key, int* maxIndex, int* minIndex) {
    int mid;
    if (lo > hi) {
        printf("Key not found\n");
        return;
    }
    mid = (lo + hi) / 2;
    if (list[mid] == key) {
        counter++;
        if (*maxIndex == -1) {
            *maxIndex = mid;
            cout << "Init max" << endl;
        }
        if (mid > *maxIndex) {
            *maxIndex = mid;
            cout << "Change max" << endl;
        }

        if (*minIndex == -1) {
            *minIndex = mid;
            cout << "Init min" << endl;
        }

        if (mid < *minIndex) {
            *minIndex = mid;
            cout << "Change min" << endl;
        }
    }
    if (mid - 1 >= 0)
        if (list[mid - 1] == key)
            binary_search(list, lo, mid - 1, key, maxIndex, minIndex);
    if (mid + 1 <= hi)
        if (list[mid + 1] == key)
            binary_search(list, mid + 1, hi, key, maxIndex, minIndex);
}



int main() {
    int min = 10;
    int max = -1;
    int arr[] = { 1,1,3,3,3,3,4,7,8,9 };

    binary_search(arr, 0, 10, 3, &max, &min);
    cout << max - min + 1 << endl;
    cout << counter;
    return 0;
}
```

What i did is, find first appearance of an element and the last appearance and deduct the indexes, But is it O(logn)?

It seems like the worst case scenario is O(n), because the recursive formula in the worst case scenario is T(n)= 2T(n/2) = O(n);

My question is, is it possible to do such thing in O(logn) ,and how will it be implemented?

Comment: Yes, [`std::equal_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range).

Comment: Yes, it can be done in O(log n). A correct binary search is O(log n), and here you need to do two of them (one for the lower bound, one of the upper). That means 2 * log(n), and in big-O, the constant factor is ignored, so it's O(log n).

Comment: A properly implemented binary search has worst case O(logN) complexity.

Comment: How can I implement for one in the lower bound? or for one in the upper bound?

Comment: The [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) offers possible implementation you can look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm gonna answer my own question here.
[image]

In pseudo code.

Answer (score 2):

> Find frequency of an element in sorted array in logn
>
> Is this possible?

Yes.

> What i did is, find first appearance of an element and the last appearance and deduct the indexes

That's a sensible algorithm.

> But is it O(logn)?

Binary search *can* be implemented in `O(log n)` and 2 binary searches can be implemented in `2 * O(log n) = O(log n)`. Therefore the described algorithm can be implemented in `O(log n)`.

Whether your implementation achieves this complexity, is another matter. But before analyzing your program, consider a flaw in it's functionality: If the key value is not in the `mid` point initially, the outputs will be left unmodified and give the wrong result. For example: try searching for frequency of `1` in your example.

It will be easier to analyze your algorithm if you implement the two binary searches individually... And it'll probably also be faster because a simple binary search can be tail call optimized.

ps. there is no need to re-implement binary search. The standard library already provides an implementation: `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound` (and `std::equal_range` which does what you're asking for fully).